# mod function using spark / java

Tags: java, dataframe, apache-spark, modulo

I have a dataframe

```
+--------------+-----------------+
|tracking_time | current_time    |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 1582037407   |1594110202934    |                
| 1582037587   |1594110202934    |                
+--------------+-----------------+
```

I want to calculate the difference in date between tracking_time and current_time , like this calcule.

```
long diffDate = (now.getTime() - tracking_date.getTime()) / (60 * 1000) % 60;
```

Note that tracking time in in unix_timestamp() and current_date is in "currentTimeMillis ().

I use the following code on spark:

```
 dataframe.withColumn("diffDate",col("current_time").minus( col("tracking_time")).divide(60*1000).mod(60));
```

But I get the following output

```
+---------------+----------------+-----------------+
|tracking_time | current_time    |  diffDate       |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1582037407   |1594110202934    |56.09211666509509|               
| 1582037587   |1594110202934    |56.089116666466  |                
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

normally mod should return the rest of the entire division. but I get a comma number.
maybe I put something wrong.

I need your help.

Thank you .

Comment: Does `tracking_time` and `current_time` values look even *close* to similar to you? They shouldn't, because `tracking_time` is in **seconds** and `current_time` is in **milliseconds**, so subtracting them from each other does results in a **meaningless** value. You need to ***divide `current_time` by 1000*** before subtracting!

Comment: `1582037407` is `2020-02-18T14:50:07Z` and `1594110202934` is `2020-07-07T08:23:22.934Z`, i.e. they are 139 days 17 hours 33 minutes and 15 seconds apart (ignoring DST), so what's the point of calculating the 33 minutes?

Comment: @Andreas thank you for ur reply. I didn't understand can you explain more .

Comment: What is 30000 milliseconds minus 25 seconds? `30000 - 25 = 29975` but 29975 is a meaningless number. It doesn't means anything, since it is neither seconds nor milliseconds. --- `30000 / 1000 - 25 = 30 - 25 = 5` is a useful value, i.e. 5 seconds, but that's not what you're doing. --- `seconds / 60 % 60` is the minutes part of an hour/minute/second time value. When your values are **139 days** apart, what is the purpose of knowing that the minute *part* is 33? I.e. for `139d 17h 33m 15s`, the value 33 is of little use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the type issues.
Mod of double will return a double.

Example:

```
df.withColumn("a", lit(3.5)).withColumn("b", col("a") % 3).show()
```

This will return you few lines of a = 3.5 and b = 0.5.

If you want integer values you would need to ceil/floor your values and then cast to IntegerType then mod will give you iteger remainders.

Edit: as pointed out by Andres, the time unit is not the same. So first you should normalise the time units.

tt = 1582037407
ct = 1594110202934

So you have a 1000x difference in measure.

(ct/1000 - tt) would make it comparable.
This will be in seconds and the difference will be a double value.
If you need it in integer cast your values. Then mode will return mod of integer, if you keep it in double it will behave as mod of double.

The other issue is that now() will be evaluated prior to serialisation so you will always get same now. Maybe that is desired, it isnt clear to me so I point it out.

If you do not want same current time then you will probably get desiered behaviour via UDF that can evaluate now() for each row. Be mindful that in that case now will be machine specific and you are running things in parrallel.

Comment: The issue is at `tracking_time` is in *seconds* and `current_time` is in *milliseconds*, so subtracting them makes no sense.

Comment: Fair point, but his question was about integer part of division: "normally mod should return the rest of the entire division. but I get a comma number." which is properly addressed in what I said, since after division he gets a double then mod operation is working in the above manner, I have to admit I missed the brackets I honestly thought he is dividing only the current_time with 60*1000 and not the substraction but even that would not make sense